# I made a twitter account that polls the RSS feed

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, twitter

You can find it [here](http://twitter.com/androidse).  It will only post one tweet per hour of the newest questions.

If anyone would like to make a better Twitter icon, please do.

Whenever we get an official domain name, the twitter name can change accordingly.

Comment: Nice work, followed.

Comment: can you rephrase this in the form of a question and answer? Then accept, and it's removed from the "unanswered" list.....

Comment: @Michael created an answers and accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to see here.... (going to accept as per Michael's suggestion).