# What does voting mean and why is it important?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, voting

*Android.StackExchange* is a site managed primarily by the community. Reputation is a general measure of engagement with the site, and as a user's reputation goes up he or she gets more privileges to help manage the site. Reputation is gained, primarily, by receiving votes on questions and answers.

However, if the community doesn't engage, **by voting**, then users don't gain reputation, thus don't get additional privileges. This means that the users are not able to self-police the community without moderator action.

**Why is it important to vote on both questions and answers, and what are these votes supposed to mean?**

Comment: Inspired by http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/710/what-does-voting-mean-and-why-is-it-important

Comment: Presumably influenced by this StackOverflow Blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/ It is also worth remembering that Accepting answers and Voting help this site to rise out of it's current Beta status into a fully fledged launch. We need a good Questions to Accepted Answers ratio, and enough users with high enough Rep to Moderate the site before we can graduate, and get a nice Android-centric design and logo.

Comment: You can see our current progress towards launch here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts as well as see the parts that we need to improve on. One of the areas that we're behind on at the moment is having enough high-rep users.

Comment: I don't think this question can be read and acted upon enough. Get out there and vote, people!

Comment: bump. vote vote vote. According to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18238/android-enthusiasts we don't have enough users with enough reputation. Make with the clicky-click, people!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voting is the currency of our site.  Each day we get 30 votes to spend. It is important that users try and use up these votes each day.  Without votes, we don't have reputation.  Without reputation, the community cannot police itself.  See the [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) for information on the reputation levels.

### Why should you vote on questions?

The more votes a question has, the more exposure it gets via the question and tag listing pages.  Questions with a higher score indicate that it is quality content.  We should strive for this quality content.

#### When should you vote up a question?

- It is well-written
- It is clear
- It is interesting
- It is useful
- You have the same question

#### When should you vote down a question?

- It cannot be answered
- It is unclear
- It contains no effort by the author

### Why should you vote on answers?

Voting on answers helps make sure that the most correct answer will float to the top and be the first answer presented to users. Obviously this is what we want. We don't want incorrect or poorly written answers to be the first thing people see. This doesn't put the site in a good light.

#### When should you vote up an answer?

- It is correct
- It is well-written
- It helps you (Important: accept the answer if it is your question)

#### When should you vote down an answer?

- It is incorrect
- It is misleading
- It doesn't answer the question

#### Notes on downvoting:

When downvoting, it is helpful to also leave a comment explaining your downvote.  This provides an opportunity for the author to improve his/her post in which case you can later reverse your vote.

Don't take a downvote personally; it costs the voter reputation it means that there is something seriously wrong with the the post. Take the time to revise the post, check your facts and references you used in your answer. If the downvoter has left a comment you can *politely* ask them to check over the revision by using the @username convention in another comment.

#### Notes on voting:

***Never*** vote based on *who* wrote the question or answer. Your vote should be solely on the content.